# Error with comments inside and expression

Tags: front-end, bugs, version-7, syntax-highlighting

I found this strange parsing error with comments inside of an expression in Version 7. And example is

```
{{1, x}, {1, y} (* {1, z (= 5+6)} *)};
```

It occurs depending on the spacing before and after the z. Playing with deleting and reinserting a blank on those positions makes it pop up after some time, and it can be corrected the same way. Here a screenshot:

[image]

Is this a feature of a bug?

Comment: I *do not* have this problem in version **7.0.1** under Windows.  What is your exact version and OS?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: V.7.0.0 on a macbook, OS X 10.9.3, and I have to play a little till it pops up.

Comment: Please define "play a little" as I wish to attempt to recreate the problem.  Is there a reason you have not updated to 7.0.1?  It should be a free upgrade to you; if you get the installer it should recognize your existing license without issue.

Comment: "play a little": At the position I indicated, switching between ", z (", ",z (", " ,z(", ",z(" in various orders and hitting return each time. And I'm not a computer person, I don't like to update things that work because sometimes there is something to fix afterwards, while I didn't think of wanting something new anyway.

Comment: For what it's worth point releases (7.0 -> 7.0.1) usually fix bugs without introducing significant functionality therefore they are (I believe) reasonably safe to install.  If you still have the 7.0.0 installer you can revert if necessary.

Comment: Even though I have been unable to reproduce this problem I am restoring the `bugs` tag.  Usually we wait for confirmation or consensus that an issue is in fact a bug, but since there are very few 7.0.0 users participating (as far as I know) this may not be possible.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: I don't understand the logic behind removing the bugs tag anyway: I think of the tags as a tool to find topics, and so when people think it's a bug (like me, even if it's not true), then this helps. It doesn't belong there just when you treat the tag as classifying note. I don't how the StackExchange government sees it.

Comment: Adding `bugs` only to confirmed bugs is convention on this particular chapter of Stack Exchange.  See: [(354)](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/354/121).  If you have a dissenting opinion on the matter please post in that Meta Q&A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a parsing error. It is a minor code editor code-coloring bug. The have been a lot of them over various *Mathematica* releases. You will even see some in the Documentation Center examples. The one you report here was already corrected in V9 (the oldest version still available to me).